# Jest assert promise resolved with object containing

Tags: promise, jestjs, assert

Say I want to test a module that returns a `Promise`:

```
function myFunc () {
    return Promise.resolve({
        anArray: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    })
}
```

Using Jest, how can I assert the length of the array contained in the object the promise resolves to?

```
describe('myFunc', () => {
  it('returns array of length 6', () => {
    expect.assertions(1)
    return expect(myFunc()).resolves // ... something here
  })
})
```

If it were synchronous, I would do something like:

```
let result = myFunc()
expect(result.anArray.length).toBe(6)
```

How does this work with Promises?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways either return the promise from the test and make the assertion in the `then` or make your test using `async/await`

```
describe('myFunc', () => {
  it('returns array of length 6', () => {
    expect.assertions(1)
    return expect(myFunc())
      .then(result =>  expect(result).toEqual([1,2,3,4,5,6]);)
  })
})

describe('myFunc',() => {
  it('returns array of length 6', async() => {
    const result = await expect(myFunc())
    expect(result).toEqual([1,2,3,4,5,6]);)
  })
})
```

The [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async) on this topic

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to use [`.resolves`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#resolves) like you were starting to do in your sample.

You just need to chain [`.toMatchObject`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchobjectobject) to the result:

```js
function myFunc () {
  return Promise.resolve({
      anArray: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  })
}

describe('myFunc', () => {
  it('returns array of length 6', () => {
    expect(myFunc()).resolves.toMatchObject({ anArray: [1,2,3,4,5,6] });  // Success!
  })
})
```

This will assert that the object has *at least* the `anArray` property set to `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` (it can have other properties as well).

Note that [PR 5364](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/5364) makes it so `resolves` validates its arguments **synchronously** so you don't even have to `return`, `await`, or use `done` if you are using `Jest` >= [`v22.2.0`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#jest-2220).

---

**Update**

Sounds like the goal is to *only assert on the length of the array*.

For that you would need to get the result of the `Promise` (as has been described in the previous answers), then use [`.toHaveLength`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavelengthnumber) to assert the length of the `anArray` property:

```js
describe('myFunc', () => {
  it('returns array of length 6', async () => {
    const result = await myFunc();
    expect(result.anArray).toHaveLength(6);  // Success!
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This was the path I was going down originally but it only works when checking the entire object, rather than something inside the object.

Comment: @sennett ah, the previous answers (including the one you accepted) compared the entire object so I assumed that's what you wanted.  I've updated my initial answer to use `toMatchObject` to **only** compare the `anArray` property of the object, as well as adding a test that **only** asserts on the `length` of the `anArray` property as was specifically requested in the question.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to pass a `done` callback, to mark your test as asynchronous and force `jest` to wait until you call `done()`:

```
describe('myFunc', () => {
  it('returns array of length 6', (done) => {
    expect.assertions(1)
    myFunc().then((values) => {
      expect(values).toEqual([1,2,3...]);
      done();
    });
  })
})
```

You can just return a Promise as well, without the need for `done`:

```
describe('myFunc', () => {
  it('returns array of length 6', () => {
    expect.assertions(1)
    return myFunc().then((values) => {
      expect(values).toEqual([1,2,3...]);
    });
  })
})
```

You can read [more about this here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous).